# Swipe gesture for number input

Tags: android, gesture, gestures, swipe

If (in Android) you wanted to write an alarm app where the user entered in the time for the alarm by swiping the hours & minutes up and down, what's the easiest way of achieving this? Is it the Swipe or Fling command?

Are there any good tutorials out there for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html)?

[Tutorial\Sample Code](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html)

Comment: That is helpful thanks. However I think that just makes use of some up/down buttons for changing the time. What I want to do is use a swiping gesture to change the time, rather like the HTC Sense apps. Cheers.